# Convert SSIS package deployment model to project deployment model

Tags: sql-server, ssis, configuration

We are converting SSIS package from package deployment model to project deployment model.
Our package deployment model SSIS package uses a config file (setup in Package Configurations menu).

I don't see Package Configurations menu in the project deployment model.

Is it correct that I can't use the same config file that I use in package deployment model in the project deployment model?

What is the easiest way to convert this config file in project deployment model?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from SQL Server SSIS 2012, there is no need anymore to use config files. Project level parameters as well as package level parameters replaced them.

SSIS Catalog keeps all these parameters in the SSISDB database. Which is much better than config files on the file system.

Check it out here: [SSIS Parameters](https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2020/07/02/ssis-parameters/)

Comment: So, I will need to manually convert the config file to either project level parameters or package level parameters, is that correct ?