# SQL Server Integration Services converting from Package to Project Deployment

Tags: sql-server, ssis

We have hundreds of existing packages that use Configurations, extensively. Each package has 3 configurations and a parent package variable. The first configuration is via a XML file and the other 2 are via a SQL Server table.

There are many variables in each package that have their value set from that SQL table.

I think that we will have a huge job ahead of us to replace those configurations but I'm hoping somebody else has faced this and come up with an approach that minimises the rewrites.

I've done a search of the net to find ideas. What I've found explains how to use Environments, project parameters and package parameters. I already know that stuff. What I'm hoping to find is an "easy" way to replace all that configuration with project deployment equivalents.

I found this answer to a similar question to mine: [Convert SSIS package deployment model to project deployment model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584163/convert-ssis-package-deployment-model-to-project-deployment-model). The requester there has asked a follow-up which is pretty much what I'm asking above but hasn't been answered.

Comment: I'm out of date on what happens when you click the button to convert from Package to Project deployment model. What happens when you do it for one project? Does it strip the Configuration or leave as is? A "helpful" thing to be aware of is a missed configuration only raises a Warning/Information event, it won't actually crash the package so converting to project deployment model, removing the config file and blocking access to the table might allow you to get converted faster and cleanup as time permits? What does the XML configure & then what is configured from tables? Edit into Q to improve